# How to merge tapply() and hist() in R?

Tags: r, plot, histogram, rstudio, tapply

How does one appropriately merge the hist() and tapply() functions in R, in order to get histograms of data subsets? When I attempt this using the standard tapply() formula `tapply(X, INDEX, FUN)`, I successfully get value outputs for each data subset, but I only get one histogram plot with the title 'Histogram of X[[4L]]'. **How can I get separate histograms for each subset?** Thanks,

Comment: Where do you want them to go exactly? Each time you call hist(), it normally erases the existing graphics device? Do you want to setup a `layout()` before your tapply to arrange them all on the same graphics device? What exactly is your desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, hist)
```

[image]

however, for multi-panel plots you might find the lattice or ggplot2 plackages more suitable.

```
library(lattice)
histogram(~ Sepal.Length | Species, iris)
```

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~ Species)
```

[image]